# How to avoid duplicate objects from two arrays after filter using java script

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i have two arrays ( busns and pc ) i want to check pc array -> pcid is match with busns array -> pcid after match i want to return pcname. final output is comming but i want to avoid duplicate. thanks in advance

[please check my attempt in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfu01g2L/)

```
const busns = [
{
 id:1,
 shopname:'New trend',
 pcid:1
},
{
 id:2,
 shopname:'Latest Beauty',
 pcid:2
},
{
 id:3,
 shopname:'Mens Style',
 pcid:1
},
{
 id:4,
 name:'Fabulook',
 pcid: 1
},
{
 id:4,
 name:'New cut',
 pcid: 2
}
]

const pc = [
       {
         pcid:1,
         pcname: 'collection1'
       },
       {
         pcid:2,
         pcname: 'collection2'
       },
       {
         pcid:3,
         pcname: 'collection3'
       },
       {
         pcid:4,
         pcname: 'collection4'
       }
    ]
```

My code :

```
busns.map(busns => {
  return pc.filter( p => {
     return busns.pcid == p.pcid
  }).map(data => {
     console.log(data.pcname)
  })
})
```

expected output while using console :

collection1

collection2

Comment: Please see this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-an-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: i tried that but somehow i'm missing little bit concept. tats why i posted here for help

Comment: Try `var ids = busns.map(x=>x.pcid); pc.filter(x=> ids.includes(x.pcid))`

Comment: @Rajesh that's an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you could use this:

> var ids = busns.map(x=>x.pcid); pc.filter(x=> ids.includes(x.pcid))

---

**Your code:**

What you are doing is,

- Looping on business array to get current PC id.
- Then you use this ID to filter out from PC's list and then use map to get name.

Now the issue with your code is, since you are looping on `busns` array, you are essentially printing the name of PC for every id.

```js
const busns = [{ id: 1, shopname: 'New trend', pcid: 1 }, { id: 2, shopname: 'Latest Beauty', pcid: 2 }, { id: 3, shopname: 'Mens Style', pcid: 1 }, { id: 4, name: 'Fabulook', pcid: 1 }, { id: 4, name: 'New cut', pcid: 2 } ]

const pc = [{ pcid: 1, pcname: 'collection1' }, { pcid: 2, pcname: 'collection2' }, { pcid: 3, pcname: 'collection3' }, { pcid: 4, pcname: 'collection4' } ]

busns.map(busns => {
  return pc.filter(p => {
    return busns.pcid == p.pcid
  }).map(data => {
    console.log(data.pcname)
  })
})
```

---

**Solution from comment:**

Instead of nested looping structure, what you can do is,

- Create a list of `pcid`s. This will help you know if pc is traded.
- Loop over `pc` array. Trades can be many but product will be finite and less in number. Use this to get a filtered list of products that are in `busns`.
- Now loop over this filtered array and retrieve names. This part was not covered in comment.

```js
const busns = [{ id: 1, shopname: 'New trend', pcid: 1 }, { id: 2, shopname: 'Latest Beauty', pcid: 2 }, { id: 3, shopname: 'Mens Style', pcid: 1 }, { id: 4, name: 'Fabulook', pcid: 1 }, { id: 4, name: 'New cut', pcid: 2 } ]

const pc = [{ pcid: 1, pcname: 'collection1' }, { pcid: 2, pcname: 'collection2' }, { pcid: 3, pcname: 'collection3' }, { pcid: 4, pcname: 'collection4' } ]

var ids = busns.map(x=>x.pcid); 
var pcNames = pc
  .filter(x=> ids.includes(x.pcid))
  .map(x=> x.pcname);

console.log(pcNames)
```

---

**Preferred solution:**

One issue with above approaches is extra iterations and duplicate `pcid` in list. So instead of using functions like `.map` + `.filter`, we can use `.reduce` and create unique list. This will keep iterations minimum.

- Create a hashMap with keys as `pcid` and value as `true`. This will create a unique id map.
- Now loop over `pc` array and check if current id is present in this object ot not. If present, push name. If not, continue.

I would suggest you to use this approach as this should be more performant. Using `.map` + `.filter` + `.indexOf` can be expensive for huge arrays.

```js
const busns = [{ id: 1, shopname: 'New trend', pcid: 1 }, { id: 2, shopname: 'Latest Beauty', pcid: 2 }, { id: 3, shopname: 'Mens Style', pcid: 1 }, { id: 4, name: 'Fabulook', pcid: 1 }, { id: 4, name: 'New cut', pcid: 2 } ]

const pc = [{ pcid: 1, pcname: 'collection1' }, { pcid: 2, pcname: 'collection2' }, { pcid: 3, pcname: 'collection3' }, { pcid: 4, pcname: 'collection4' } ]

var ids = busns.reduce((acc, cur) => acc[cur.pcid] = true && acc, {});

var pcNames = pc.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if(ids[cur.pcid]) {
    acc.push(cur.pcname);
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(pcNames)
```

Comment: thanks for best solution and reduce method explanation

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
pc.filter(p => busns.map(busns => busns.pcid).includes(p.pcid)).forEach(data => console.log(data.pcname));
```